# Nancy Stateless Auth Config doesn't accept IPrincpal

Tags: c#, authentication, nancy

I'm attempting to implement stateless auth for my API with nancy but I've encountered an issue after following the [sample stateless project](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/master/samples/Nancy.Demo.Authentication.Stateless). When I create my [StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration](https://github.com/TheDarkVoid/Aoba/blob/master/Aoba.Server/Aoba.cs#L21)

```
    new StatelessAuthenticationConfiguration(nancyContext =>
    {
        var apiKey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiKeyModel>(nancyContext.Request.Body.AsString()).ApiKey;
        return GetUserFromApiKey(apiKey);
    });
```

it gives me an error about being unable to implicitly cast the [IPrincipal](https://github.com/TheDarkVoid/Aoba/blob/master/Aoba.Server/Aoba.cs#L85)

```
    internal static IPrincipal GetUserFromApiKey(string apiKey)
    {
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {apiKey}");
                cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT username FROM apiKeys WHERE apiKey = {apiKey}";
                string username = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
                    return null;
                else
                    return new ClaimsPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(username, "stateless"));//new UserModel(username);
            }
        }
    }
```

I give it.  I've tried casting to `IUserIdentity` and even using my own [UserModel](https://github.com/TheDarkVoid/Aoba/blob/master/Aoba.Server/Models/UserModel.cs)

```
class UserModel : IUserIdentity
{
    public string UserName { get; }

    public IEnumerable<string> Claims { get; }

    public UserModel(string username)
    {
        UserName = Uri.EscapeDataString(username);
    }


}
```

implementing `IUserIdentity`. This yields no error but the user doesn't get authenticated. The user still can't access my [secure module](https://github.com/TheDarkVoid/Aoba/blob/master/Aoba.Server/Modules/APIModule.cs)

```
public class APIModule : NancyModule
{
    public APIModule() : base("/api")
    {
        StatelessAuthentication.Enable(this, Aoba.StatelessConfig);
        this.RequiresAuthentication();

        Post["/"] = _ =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Context.CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated());
            return new Response { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
        };
    }
}
```

despite making it past all the required validation and having a correct apiKey. From my testing it would seem that the user never gets assigned to the nancy context. The configuration is being used and the user is obtained via the apiKey but it never gets set. Is there something I am missing? Full project can be found [here](https://github.com/TheDarkVoid/Aoba/tree/master/Aoba.Server) if you want to inspect the project further.

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid The code was linked, but I've now also added it inline.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was with my query to get the user from an apiKey. Below is the correction, now everything works as expected.

```
    internal static UserModel GetUserFromApiKey(string apiKey)
    {
        using (var con = GetConnection())
        {
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Key: {apiKey}");
                cmd.CommandText = $"SELECT username FROM apiKeys WHERE apikey = '{apiKey}'";
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (!reader.HasRows)
                        return null;
                    reader.Read();
                    string username = reader.GetString(0);
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
                        return null;
                    else
                        return new UserModel(username);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```